# Pytest capture stdout of a certain test

Tags: python, pytest

Is there a way get the `Captured stdout call` just for a specific test without failing the test?

So lets say I have 10 tests, plus a test_summary.  test_summary really just prints some kind of summary/statistics of the tests, but in order for me to get that output/printout, I have to currently fail that test intentionally.  Of course this test_summary run last using pytest-ordering.  But is there a better way to get that results without failing the test? Or should it not be in a test, but more in the conftest.py or something?  Please advice on the best practice and how I can get this summary/results (basically a printout from a specific script I wrote)

Comment: You could run with `pytest -s`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, to answer your exact question:

> Is there a way get the `Captured stdout call` just for a specific test without failing the test?

You can add a custom section that mimics `Captured stdout call` and is printed on test success. The output captured in each test is stored in the related `TestReport` object and is accessed via `report.capstdout`. Example impl: add the following code to a `conftest.py` in your project or tests root directory:

```
import os

def pytest_terminal_summary(terminalreporter, exitstatus, config):
    # on failures, don't add "Captured stdout call" as pytest does that already
    # otherwise, the section "Captured stdout call" will be added twice
    if exitstatus > 0:
        return
    # get all reports
    reports = terminalreporter.getreports('')
    # combine captured stdout of reports for tests named `<smth>::test_summary`
    content = os.linesep.join(
        report.capstdout for report in reports
        if report.capstdout and report.nodeid.endswith("test_summary")
    )
    # add custom section that mimics pytest's one
    if content:
        terminalreporter.ensure_newline()
        terminalreporter.section(
            'Captured stdout call',
            sep='-',
            blue=True,
            bold=True,
        )
        terminalreporter.line(content)
```

This will add a custom section `Captured stdout call` that will only print the output captured for the test whose ID ends with `test_summary` (if you have multiple test functions named `test_summary`, extend the check). To distinct both sections, the custom one has a blue header; if you want it to match the original, remove color setting via `blue=True` arg.

---

Now, to address your actual problem:

> `test_summary` really just prints some kind of summary/statistics of the tests

Using a test for custom reporting smells a lot like a workaround to me; why not collect the data in the tests and add a custom section printing that data afterwards? To collect the data, you can e.g. use the [`record_property`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest.junitxml.record_property) fixture:

```
def test_foo(record_property):
    # records a key-value pair
    record_property("hello", "world")


def test_bar(record_property):
    record_property("spam", "eggs")
```

To collect and output the custom properties recorded, slightly alter the above hookimpl. The data stored via `record_property` is accessible via `report.user_properties`:

```
import os


def pytest_terminal_summary(terminalreporter, exitstatus, config):
    reports = terminalreporter.getreports('')
    content = os.linesep.join(
        f'{key}: {value}' for report in reports
        for key, value in report.user_properties
    )
    if content:
        terminalreporter.ensure_newline()
        terminalreporter.section(
            'My custom summary',
            sep='-',
            blue=True,
            bold=True
        )
        terminalreporter.line(content)
```

Running the above tests now yields:

```
$ pytest test_spam.py 
=============================== test session starts ================================
platform linux -- Python 3.9.0, pytest-6.1.2, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/oleg.hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow/so-64812992
plugins: metadata-1.10.0, json-report-1.2.4, cov-2.10.1, forked-1.3.0, xdist-2.1.0
collected 2 items                                                                  

test_spam.py ..                                                              [100%]

-------------------------------- My custom summary ---------------------------------
hello: world
spam: eggs
================================ 2 passed in 0.01s =================================
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard pytest terminal reporter.

```
def test_a(request):
    reporter = request.config.pluginmanager.getplugin("terminalreporter")
    reporter.write_line("Hello", yellow=True)
    reporter.write_line("World", red=True)
```

The reporter is the standard plugin available for all pytest versions that I can recall. It is not documented unfortunately while the API is pretty stable.

You can find `TerminalReporter` class on pytest's github: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/src/_pytest/terminal.py

The most useful for you methods are probably `ensure_line()`, `write()`, `flush()` and the absolute champion -- `write_line()` that just do all work.

Available styles could be found at https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/src/_pytest/_io/terminalwriter.py

```
_esctable = dict(
    black=30,
    red=31,
    green=32,
    yellow=33,
    blue=34,
    purple=35,
    cyan=36,
    white=37,
    Black=40,
    Red=41,
    Green=42,
    Yellow=43,
    Blue=44,
    Purple=45,
    Cyan=46,
    White=47,
    bold=1,
    light=2,
    blink=5,
    invert=7,
)
```

Lowercased styles are for the foreground, capitalized are for background.

For example, the yellow on the green text should be printed as

```
reporter.write_line("Text", yellow=True, Green=True)
```

I hope this instruction can help.

Comment: Thanks alot for the info.  For my problem, hoefling's answer is more what I am looking for.  But I will definitely keep this in mind, this is very useful and will definitely use this style in the future as well