# pytest: only print summary on stdout, but capture test output to file

Tags: python, pytest

What I want to achieve is the following:

When running pytest, i want only to see a line per test, with nothing on stdout. If a test fails, then output of the failing test should be printed. This is the default behavior of pytest and it suits me well.

However, I also want the stdout and stderr of all tests to be written to a log file.
Preferably, written so that the output from different tests can be distinguished.
I couldn't find an option for doing so.

In
[Pytest capture stdout of a certain test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64812992/pytest-capture-stdout-of-a-certain-test)
a hook is added which does something similar (but for a subset of tests). I could adapt this, but I was wondering if there was not something already in pytest? Or a plugin?