# how to make pytest output printed messages from a pytest conftest

Tags: pytest

My project uses a conftest file for some sanity checks, fixture definitions and other things, and I would like that print statements which I make directly from within my conftest.py itself ― will actually be printed to the console (stdout) once encountered within the flow of my conftest.py ― *regardless of whether pytest is globablly capturing and supressing stdout for the **tests being run** or not*.

(i.e. without requiring use of the `-s` option, which would flood stdout with all test stdout outputs).

So my MVE code for this is simply a conftest.py file containing:

```
print('hello from conftest')
```

It seems that by default, `print()` statements from within the conftest file itself are not funneled through to the console when `-s` is not used, and I would like them to *be* funneled out even when `-s` is not used, to make developers observe those messages as they run the tests.

Can this be accomplished without sacrificing the simplicity and robustness of the configuration process?

#### Some possible directions which I'm not sure of

I could possibly use capsys which is mentioned on a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67580700/1509695) in a different context, but am not sure how that kind of approach can be applied to a conftest rather than to a test function ...

P.S. I stumbled upon a different form of writing to stdout from pytest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64816814/1509695), which I would equally or even more favorably use instead of `print()` statements if it would cleanly yield the same effect, it may sound like a related feature, if that's really a supported feature these days.

Thanks!

---

**pytest version 7.4*

Comment: Where do you consider to add those prints (within fixtures ? globally ? related to test execution ? )
I guess that hooks is the solution here but it could depends on what is the goal you try to achieve

Comment: Just inside my single global conftest.py ... in its own lines of code, not in anything that it calls to

Comment: Sorry for asking again : can you give a usecase example ? Just in order to understand what you try to achieve ? Do you want those prints to appear when you run the pytest command line ?

Answer (score 3):

In your `conftest.py`, assuming that is where you want to print, and if you are using Linux, macOS, or WSL:

```
with open("/dev/tty", "w") as tty:
    print("<<<conftest>>>", file=tty)
```

and this will be printed regardless of `-s`.